# load json into a select tag +js

Tags: javascript, json

how to populate this json into a  select tag

```
var data = {
"266": "Andy Employee II",
"26": "Annette Oliveira",
"214": "Edwina Umeyor",
"39": "Eva Britton",
"193": "Leigh Otterson",
"68": "Louise Edelston",
"71": "Margaret Williams",
"97": "Simon Harris"
};
```

[Online to edit link here.](http://jsfiddle.net/isaacrajaei/5TLbd/1/)

Comment: I mean  select tag <select><option></option></select>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to iterate over the JSON array using jquery.each.

```
jQuery.each(json_data, function(index, value) {
    $("#myselect").append("<option value='" + index + "'>" + value + "</option>");
});
```

EDIT: Per the comment below -- you will have to parse the JSON structure with $.parseJSON() first and then run the above code on the resulting value (unless you retrieve the original data with $.getJSON, in which case it will be already parsed when you receive it.

Comment: This is Good but for array like : var states_array = ['Texas', 'Alabama', 'Illinois'];

Answer (score 2):

There are a ton of ways to do this: you can build up an HTML string and stuff it into the DOM, you could create the `select` tag and append `option` tags to it one by one, or you could use one of the many client-side frameworks, most of which have ways to do this via templating.

Just for fun, here's how you could do this in pure JS, no frameworks:

```
var data = {
  "266": "Andy Employee II",
  "26": "Annette Oliveira",
  "214": "Edwina Umeyor",
  "39": "Eva Britton",
  "193": "Leigh Otterson",
  "68": "Louise Edelston",
  "71": "Margaret Williams",
  "97": "Simon Harris"
};

// Grab a reference to the element to which 
// which we want to append the select tag, in 
// this case the body.  
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

// Create the select tag
var select = document.createElement('select');

var key, option, text;

// Loop over our data, creating an option tag
// for each and appending it to the select tag.
for (key in data) {
  option = document.createElement('option');
  option.value = key;
  text = document.createTextNode(data[key]);
  option.appendChild(text);
  select.appendChild(option);    
}

// Insert the select tag into the DOM.
body.appendChild(select);
```

[And here's a fiddle of this in action](http://jsfiddle.net/2WHEt/)

Comment: Hi mate . I have the element already. I need to reload into it

Answer (score 0):

In this case I had Json from Ajax callback. So You have to make sure the Jsone is not string.

```
data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);    
var select = $('#ShiftUserId');
```

And Then

```
$.each(data, function(key, val){
var option = $('<option/>');
option.attr('value', key)
      .html(val)
      .appendTo(select);
});
```

OR

```
    data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);        
    data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);    
    jQuery.each(data, function(index, value) {
        console.log(index);
        $('#ShiftUserId').append( $('<option></option>').val(index).html(value) );
    });
```

OR

Answer below